# Place a circle with notification count on top corner

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any html technique to place circular notification on top right of rectangular div like image uploaded below[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample html? At least demonstrate what you have tried so far!

Comment: @Paulie_D Acctually I am new to html so i created only a div with height 100px and width 100px only
<div style="width:100px;height:100px">
</div>

Comment: @SunithSaga Always start with experimenting first. Now, remember you can always learn about existing website's by doing an inspect element in chrome. If you are beginner with html, understand how to add a control over another and what positioning of a control means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B6pTd/

The trick is the relative and absolute positioning. The border radius is just for fun. Any typically you need to post your attempted solutions.

```css
.container {
  background-color:#000;
  padding:20px;
}
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#555;
  border:#aaa;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin:20px;
  position:relative;
}
#noti-count {
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
  right:-15px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
#noti-count div {
  margin-top:7px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'>
    <div id='noti-count'><div>2</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zekLW/)** ([updated](http://jsfiddle.net/zekLW/2/) slightly)

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid grey;        
    position:relative;
}
div:after{
    content:'1';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    border-radius:99px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why did this answer get down vote

Comment: Someone has got pretty downvote-happy in this thread..

Answer (score 1):

You may use absolute positioning for circle element nested inside rectangle div. Another approach could be to use :after or :before instead of nested element in rectangle.